# VirtualBox Python API - remote access

Tags: python, virtualbox

I'm trying to run virtual machine set on Computer with Windows 7 (my main laptop) from my netbook (Ubuntu system).
On Ubuntu I've prepared python script:

```
from vboxapi import VirtualBoxManager
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/myLogin/Downloads/sdk/bindings/webservice/python/lib")

mgr = VirtualBoxManager("WEBSERVICE", {'url':'myIP', 'user':'myServerLogin', 'password':'myPassthere'})
vbox = mgr.vbox
name = "Muszelek"
mach = vbox.findMachine(name)
session = mgr.mgr.getSessionObject(vbox)
progress = mach.launchVMProcess(session, "gui", "")
progress.waitForCompletion(-1)
mgr.closeMachineSession(session)
```

I'm getting error:

```
Installation problem: check that appropriate libs in place
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vboxapi/__init__.py", line 981, in __init__
    self.vbox = self.platform.getVirtualBox()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vboxapi/__init__.py", line 856, in getVirtualBox
    return self.connect(self.url, self.user, self.password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vboxapi/__init__.py", line 910, in connect
    self.vbox = self.wsmgr.logon(self.user, self.password)
  File "/home/karolinka/Downloads/sdk/bindings/webservice/python/lib/VirtualBox_wrappers.py", line 11790, in logon
    req=IWebsessionManager_logonRequestMsg()
NameError: global name 'IWebsessionManager_logonRequestMsg' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vmmach.py", line 5, in <module>
    mgr = VirtualBoxManager("WEBSERVICE", {'url':'myIP', 'user':'myComputerLogin', 'password':'myPass'})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vboxapi/__init__.py", line 985, in __init__
    raise ne
NameError: global name 'IWebsessionManager_logonRequestMsg' is not defined
```

Any idea how could I solve this issue?
Is it problem with libs on my Windows Machine?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem on my Mac. The issue is that VirtualBox_wrappers.py imports VirtualBox_client.py (which defines the global name in question) in a try block and  continues (pass) if it can not be imported

`try:
 from VirtualBox_client import *
except:
 pass`

the issue is that VirtualBox_client.py depends on ZSI, which was not installed, so the import failed. Once I did

`easy_install zsi`

everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the class is not found! Have you tried to look for the webservice api if they are available?
I had a similar issue, I looked in /usr/lib/virtualbox/sdk/bindings and I didn't find the webservice folder only xpcom was in there, so I just included the webservice folder from the sdk and all worked fine.